# After returning a float value from a method and trying to print it, the printed value is always wrong (although the method does works as intended)

Tags: c

I wrote a simple method to calculate an arithmetic mean like so:

```
float arithmetic_mean(int a[], int n)
{
float sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    sum = sum / (float)n;
    return sum;
}
```

I wanted to check it in main:

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1,3,5,1,6,7 };
    float check = arithmetic_mean(a, 6);
    printf("%f", check);
    return 0;
}
```

even though the value the method returns is correct (=3.833333 as checked by printing it before returning it), when I try to print it in main I get 9 as the output.

I'm really new to C language and stuff like this always seems to happen with floats - I'll write a method that works and return a float - and the returned value would be something seemingly random. What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://onlinegdb.com/r1BaCP5Vw

Comment: You need to provide a code for *entire program* that still produces the same problem.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala This is the entire code. I wrote it again in a completely new project and this time I'm getting 6 for some reason http://prntscr.com/ug4qab

Comment: @Hatulim that is the **code you need to present in entirety in the question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (which I *can* reproduce with MSVC) is that you are calling the `arithmetic_mean` function (from `main`) ***before*** you have defined it. Thus, the compiler uses a *default* definition of the function, which is that it returns an `int` type ... and the actual (`float`) value returned just happens to have a bit pattern that represents `9` when interpreted as an `int`.

You can leave the **definition** of the function where it is (after `main`) **so long as you provide a forward declaration** of the function, so that the compiler knows what the return type is:

```c
float arithmetic_mean(int a[], int n); // Forward declaration of the function!

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1,3,5,1,6,7 };
    float check = arithmetic_mean(a, 6);
    printf("%f\n", check);
    return 0;
}

// The actual DEFINITION (including the body) of the function can follow...
```

Turning on compiler warnings would have helped you spot this! For example, without the forward declaration, MSVC gives this:

> warning C4013: 'arithmetic_mean' undefined; assuming extern returning
> int

Comment: Using a C compile instead of MSVC garbage would have helped a lot - GCC for example **errors out** with default settings.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala clang-cl also gives an error. However, I'm not sure what the actual C Standard says about such a case ... MSVC has been known (on occasions) to be correct.

Comment: It has been a constraint violation for at least 21 years and compilers must diagnose. It also makes no sense for the compiler to error out because compiling the program does not make any sense at that point.